# Ontology design : class or individuals

Tags: owl, ontology, protege, protege4

Designing an ontology where I need to capture microstrategy documents and what kind of information it contains. for e.g. below are three mstr documents.

```
1. Finance summary (has finance inforamtion)
2. Country finance summary (has finance & country info)
3. Invest to grow country finance summary (has finance, country, invest to grow country info)
```

Along with that I have defined information classes like below.

```
1. Finance
2. Country
3. InvestToGrowCountry (subclass of country)
```

There is a predicate/property called hasInformation which joins documents with information classes. 
My question is - should i create mstr documents as subclasses of documents and define hasInformation predicate to it or create individuals/instances of documents ?

Please note each document will also have property like name, projectName, url, parameters. Should this property be defined as datatype property of individuals or classes?

Appreciate your help...Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In OWL classes represent sets. So you can have a class `:MicrostrategyManual` with members, which are URIs representing concrete files or paper copies, which can be classified as `a :MicrostrategyManual`.

Regarding:

> There is a predicate/property called hasInformation which joins
>   documents with information classes.

the only (except when going with option 3 below) property that can link individual with a class is `rdf:type` and the one between classes is `rdfs:subClassOf`. When you want to relate a certain property to an OWL class in some way, you hav etwo options: either use the class for domain and range (rarely a good practice), or when you include the property in the class description (necessary conditions for classification, using `rdfs:subClassOf`), or definition (necessary and sufficient conditions for classification, using `owl:equivalentClass`).

Depending on what you objective is, you can design your ontology in a different way. Here are two options:

1. If you want to just classify documents, then you can define categories as individuals, members of `skos:Concept` where you can group them in a `skos:Collection` that would serve as a "code list". Then you can relate your individuals 2 and 3 in the following way:

`:InvestToGrowCountry skos:broader :Country`

2. If you want to relate your documents to the resources they contain, which could be classified in different way, then you can keep the approach with the information classes.

Regarding document properties, if you have some classes of documents for which there should have the same meta-data as the individual documents, then these should be defined as annotation properties. It would be better to re-use as much as possible those from core vocabularies/ontologies. For example, for name it would be good to use `rdfs:label` or have your `:documentName` as sub-property of `rdfs:label`. And then you can use datatype properties to further describe your documents. However, in some cases, when you want to further describe this characteristics (e.g. when you want to manage their life-cicle), it could consider using object properties, instead of annotation and datatype properties.

3. There is also a middle way, applying the OWL2 [punning](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F12%3A_Punning) feature, but as I have no experience with it, I don't know what are the risks.
4. Rename your classes as `:CountryDocument` etc, and classify your documents (directly or through inference over other properties), so the problem with `:hasInformation` is dissolved as it won't be needed, not for this purpose anyway.

Comment: Thanks Ivo
Do not completely understand your answer as you have used skos in it not much familiar with. Started designing an ontology using protege tool.
I would like to keep information classes as they are kind of information domain in ontology which has some sub classes like metrics.
Regarding documents,
1. If i keep it as individuals then not sure how can I relate it with Information domain classes.
2. If i keep it as classes then I could define Object property (hasInformation) and relate them under subClass Of like hasInformation some country
Please help to correct my understanding.

Comment: My understanding of ontology is beginner so pls bear my stupid questions and help me to correct my OWL vocabulary :)

Comment: If you have documents as individuals, you should either consider having also your classes as individuals, as suggested in Option1, or go for Option3. If you want to keep your information classes, then you should increase the chain of your relations by treating you documents as information carriers and link them to other individuals with your property `:hasInformation`, and make those other individuals members of your information classes. And here's a 4th option: rename you classes as `:CountryDocument` etc, and classify you documents directly, so the problem with `:hasInformation` is dissolved

Comment: Thanks Ivo. I would like to keep property :hasInformation so I can do sparql query to fetch document by the kind of information it contains. I dint get 'make those other individuals members of your information classes'. Can you please explain this part?

Comment: For example, and individual Document1  `:hasInformation :CountryInformation-A` and `:CountryInformation-A a :Country`, where `:CountryInformation-A` is also an individual.

Comment: Here, Cant we directly link document indiviudual to :Country class like below ? Creating a dummy individual for information class does not sound good.

`individual Document1 :hasInformation :Country`

Comment: If you go with option 3 yes. You just create a new individual with the same IRI as the class. I would suggest that you read the whole answer once again. Most of your comments are answered there already.